# Sci-Fi Golden Age, aliens who see X-rays

Tags: story-identification, aliens, short-stories

Around 1980, I read an anthology of stories by a Sci-Fi author from the 1930s. The aliens portrayed in these succinct short stories were extremely different from Earth creatures, and their peculiar bodies, psychologies, and cultures were key elements. I remember aliens with sideways, drum-shaped heads (no faces) who could see in the X-ray part of the spectrum. Also, a human-chasing alien cop or defender of some kind on its homeworld -- the human escaped by hiding in a tree or something, remembering that these aliens "never look up". And, a story that included aliens who ceremonially collected jewels and practiced ritual group suicide? The book noted that this author was not well-known. I think the editor also commented wryly on the quantly stereotyped international characters (American, English, French, German, Chinese).

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try either "The Best of Stanley G. Weinbaum" published in 1979 or "The Best of Raymond Z. Gallun" published in 1978.